# How do I load a page and immediately edit the DOM in electron?

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm trying to create a markdown editor.

So far: I have loaded the `index` page. I'm using `fs.readdir` to get the titles of all the markdown files and display them in the sidebar. Then, on clicking on of these title `#content` get's the content.

```
   module.exports = (win) => { 
        fs.readdir( './data', (err, data) =>{
        data.map(title => {    
          if(title.split('.md').length==2){
            el = document.createElement("li"); // get gave it the title ..
            el.addEventListener('click', function(e){
              fs.readFile(`./data/${title}`, (err, data) => {
                document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = data;
              });
            })
            document.getElementById('titles').appendChild(el) // title are on the page
```

**The problem is when I introduce another page**

I have a preferences page

```
win.loadURL(path.join('file://', __dirname, '../static/preferences.html'))
```

It has the same sidebar, hence I import the same code to get the titles. But now when I click one of the links, I don't want `document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = data;` but I want to load the `index` page **and then** inject the content

**So far I tried this**

```
const checkPageState = (pageName, callback) => {
  if(pageName === "preferences"){
    ipcRenderer.send(GO_TO_PAGE, 'index')
  }
  setTimeout(callback(), 1000);
}
...
el.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    checkPageState(win, ()=>{
      fs.readFile(`./data/${title}`, (err, data) => {
       if (err) throw err;
     fileDir = `./data/${title}`;
     document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = data;
    });
  })
})
```

My thinking was `ipcRenderer.send(GO_TO_PAGE, 'index')` would load the index page (which it does) when wait for a bit and then inject the data into the `index` page. It doesn't!

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently tried to do this as well and it was kinda tricky but I found something that worked:

In electron when it tries to go to another page I stop it from going to it with:

```
win.webContents.on('will-navigate', function (evt, url) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    win.webContents.executeJavaScript('makeHiddenPageIframe("' + url + '");');
});
```

Then it calls the `makeHiddenPageIframe` function defined on the page.

Then in the page I define the `makeHiddenPageIframe` function:

```
function makeHiddenPageIframe (url) {
    var hiddenPage = document.createElement("iframe");
    hiddenPage.setAttribute("src", url);
    hiddenPage.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(hiddenPage);
    hiddenPage.onload = function () {
        var frameDocument = hiddenPage.document;
        if (hiddenPage.contentDocument) {
            frameDocument = hiddenPage.contentDocument;
        } else if (hiddenPage.contentWindow) {
            frameDocument = hiddenPage.contentWindow.document;
        }
        document.open();
        document.write(frameDocument.documentElement.innerHTML);
        document.close();
        window.history.pushState("", document.title, url.replace('https://' + window.location.hostname, ''));
    }
}
```

This then makes a iframe and loads the page in there then once it has loaded copy all the html from the iframe to the parent window so it seems like the switch happened instantly.

Also the `window.history.pushState` thing at the bottom was when you overwrite the html the url stays the same so when you reload it goes back to the original page but the `window.history.pushState` changes the url without reloading the page.

Any form of navigation will do the iframe load so you would keep your `win.loadURL(` to go to another markdown page.

[The `'will-navigate'` event docs.](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#event-will-navigate)

[`window.history.pushState` ref.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3354511/6577664)

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks, where is `makeHiddenPageIframe` defined? in the page I'm going into or in the page I'm trying to leave

Comment: In the page you're trying to leave, although to be safe it should probably be defined in both.

Comment: I think I understand the code and the logic. I've read the docs on 'will-navigate' but can't seem to get it working. I can seem to even trigger that `will-navigate` event let alone proceed with `makeHiddenPageIframe`. In the root I have `main.js` that's where I declare `win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})` and under it I added `will-navigate` and see if it prevents and logs anything and it doesn't. Never mind, I'll get there. Thanks for getting me in the right direction, it must be my code.

Comment: huh, that's odd. It might be that the variable name for your window is different and it's just a copy paste error but aside from that I don't know what might be wrong. If you post the code where you're creating the window I might be able to help a bit more.

Comment: I found this https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/8841 copied exactly what sebastianseilund has and got the exact same result. `did-navigate` works `will-navigate` doesn't.

Comment: I'm new at this. Apparently, adding `sandbox: false` get's it working. I'll have to search that later as to why but at least now I got `will-navigate` working as it should

Comment: Good to hear you found a solution :). Now that it's firing does the delayed page loads work?

Comment: I sure I'll get it working, but there seem to be a totally different problem, the moment I add `webPreferences`, `require is not defined` :). I come back to your code late. It clearly works but I don't know why it's acting out at my end. Thanks again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179236/discussion-between-mike-and-relidon).